# Reference for Algebraic Topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I know undergraduate algebra (groups, rings, fields, Galois etc), undergraduate differential geometry, undergraduate real/complex analysis and now I feel as though to get to the next level, i should be learning algebraic topology (so i can finally understand what people are talking about when they say homology). I like learning about the structure of things, and i was told that algebraic topology was one of the major sparks of category theory. Im looking for a reference on algebraic topology (a first course), which is as categorical of an approach as possible- given my background of basically 1 year grad.

Comment: Bredon.${}{}{}$

Comment: Most algebraic topology texts use groupoids, a special case of categories,  only partially or not at all. Compare the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one/46808#46808

Answer (score 3):

A lot of category-theory (model cats) stuff can be found in May's "Concise" and "More Concise". I don't know if this is what you want.

If by "categorical approach" you mean an approach full of commutative diagrams (which is cat. theory, but not made explicit and well, *scary*) and a few figures and geometrical reasonings (like Hatcher's book or Milnor's characteristic classes), then **tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology** is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I got a lot of help from Rotman's *An Introduction to Algebraic Topology* to get used to categories and commutative diagrams. It is written in quite an algebraic viewpoint, and it's easy to read.