# Learning resources for Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, book-recommendation

this new course I'm starting my last year of my math's degree and I was looking for some resources for Algebraic Topology to have a look in these last few weeks before I start my classes again.

To give an orientation of my current level, this past year I've taken a semester course in introductory algebraic topology: mainly the fundamental group, the computation of $\pi_1(S^1)$, Van Kampen's theorem and as an application we proved the classification theorem for compact surfaces without boundary. I've also been interested on category theory throughout this year and I'm quite comfortable with basic categorical notions: naturality and Yoneda, limits of diagrams, adjunctions... For some reference to the literature I've been using, for algebraic topology I've been following mainly Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" 1st chapter (except covering spaces which we didn't have time to study in the course) and for Category Theory I've been working on several books in the introductory level: Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0" and "Topology: A Categorical Approach" for motivating some concepts and afterwards I've used Awodey's "Category Theory" and in a slightly more advanced level Riehl's "Category Theory in Context".

I need suggestions to continue my study path on algebraic topology (and category theory) but I haven't found many video lectures available on these subjects which can help me with my study. I watched some of the lectures of Pierre Albin which can be found in YouTube but they practically followed the same ideas as Hatcher's book. Can anyone give me some recommendations on further literature, lectures notes and specially lectures videos (if there exist) which may be interesting on my level (perhaps some introduction to covering spaces or homology theory), and preferably relying heavily in a more categorical/algebraic approach?

Comment: I’ve heard good things about May’s *Concise Algebraic Topology*. I’ve also heard it’s hard.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811242/reference-for-algebraic-topology?rq=1).

Comment: Do you have a career goal in mind? If you are considering graduate school in mathematics, then I encourage you to learn how to learn from reading: don't rely on videos. The farther you go in mathematics, the sparser the coverage by videos. The books you've mentioned are fine places to continue. For algebraic topology, try Hatcher, May, Rotman, Switzer, and others: it is helpful to see multiple approaches, and some may resonate with you more than others.